# Serializable Isolation Level

Tags: database, serialization

If serializable isolation level is valid, what is the content of table X ?

Because of serializability, I think that transaction B cannot perform any operation. Thus, row b is not placed in the table X, and delete row b operation of transaction A is not performed. As a result, table X only includes row a; however, this theory is rejected by my professor without any explanation.

```
   Transaction A     Transaction B

1) Begin             ....
2) Insert row a      Begin
3) ....              Insert row b
4) ....              Delete row a
5) Delete row b      ....
6) Commit            ....
7)                   Commit
```

Can anyone explain why my theory is false ?

Answer (score 0):

The isolation level pertains only to the local transaction and its view of the data, not to other transactions.  Other connected clients can see all manner of strange data because they are not part of the isolation that either transaction has.  At least in MySQL, serializable isolation level does not hold any table locks.  Therefore, TXA is not blocking other writes from happening.

TXA will affect zero rows at t5 and complete.

TXB will affect zero rows at t4 and complete.

The table will have 2 rows, a and b.

With other isolation levels, the results will vary.

With table locks, the timing looks like this:

```
0) Begin             ....
1) LOCK TBL WRITE    ....
2) Insert row a      Begin
3) ....              ....
4) ....              ....
5) Delete row b      ....
6) Commit            ....
8) UNLOCK            ....
7)                   Insert row b
8)                   Delete row a
9)                   Commit
```